# Tomcat: "The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly"

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, prompt, catalina

I'm getting this error on my Windows XP when trying to run the startup.bat file. However, I have set my environment variables as follows:

CLASSPATH: `(other stuff);.;C:\Desktop\IconesDesktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.56`

PATH: `(other stuff);%CATALINA_HOME%\bin`

CATALINA_HOME: `C:\Desktop\IconesDesktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.56`

It seems right for me.

Comment: On Windows you might have to quit and restart the command prompt to get the environment variables to take hold

Comment: Thanks, but I already did it

Comment: where/how do you set environment variables? in the command prompt, can you 'echo %CATALINA_HOME%' to check it is set? Also, what does 'dir %CATALINA_HOME%\bin' do?

Comment: The first command showed it is set, but the second resulted in the following error:"the system couldnt find the specified path" or something like it.

Comment: Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/579159/the-catalina-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-this-environment. Same symptoms as you've described. Your paths don't seem to show the problem (terminating semi-colon) as posted, so please double check.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this could be due to not restarting your cmd.
Try restarting your cmd, this helped me.
Or try to provide administrator privileges.